# Sum of LOV where we have duplicate records

Tags: saql, help

I need some help, I am trying to create a lens to give me a sum of LOV. My data set has duplicated rows because of multiple campaigns attached so the sum is giving me an inflated number.

is there a way to get this accurately, the below saql sums up everything

```
q = load "Final_Attribution1"; 
q = filter q by 'StageName' == "Closed Won";
q = filter q by date('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month', 'CloseDate_Day') in ["current year".."current year"];

// Use first subquery to calculate the sum of 'LOV_in_GBP__c' for each unique 'ID'
q = group q by 'Id';
q = foreach q generate 'Id', sum('LOV_in_GBP__c') as 'TotalRevenue';

// Use second subquery to calculate the total sum of 'LOV_in_GBP__c'
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate sum('TotalRevenue') as 'A';

q = limit q 25000;
```

I only want to to sum up everything once based on opportunity id

thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miGGZOCEHPM&list=PLKOdzhrd9Dx6--FBk_TyGL1VthmW6MfVl and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157676/in-analytics-wave-how-to-sum-values-from-a-related-parent-object-when-there-ar